# System resets to login screen spontaneously

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz, lightdm

Now I'm experiencing spontaneous resets of the desktop environment (when logged in and working normally), where the screen will go black, then reset to the login screen.

- The resets appear to be random, though there is a chance it occurs more when using Nautilus.
- The screen goes black instantly, e.g. there is nothing like a disappearing launcher or window borders.

Where can I begin finding the cause?

Info:

- I've recently upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10, then 12.04.
- Using Nvidia drivers "current" (295.40-0ubuntu1)

Comment: If the X server crashes it will go back to the login screen. Would you be so nice as to give us more information regarding your graphics setup (Graphic card model and the driver you use are a good start, /var/log/Xorg.0.log might also contain hints what goes wrong)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Nvidia graphics card? If so, try Unity-2D (in login screen). This might be this problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/973096 .

Comment: I don't know if I'm going to use Unity 2D or install different drivers (still reading through the comments on that page), but it appears that's the bug I'm suffering from.

Comment: It seems Nvidia is working on it.

Comment: This happens very occasionally to me and I'm running Unity 2D

Comment: I have an Intel Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller and Unity spontaneously logs out for me too, usually under load.